# Unable to get OleDbFactory from DbConnection

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a short method to get a Data Adapter from a connection:

```
Private Function GetDataAdapter(conn As DbConnection) As DbDataAdapter
    Dim factory As DbProviderFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(conn)
    If factory Is Nothing Then Throw New Exception("Unable to identify connection type")
    Return factory.CreateDataAdapter()
End Function
```

This code works with two of my three connection types, Sql and Db2.  However with OleDb, `.GetFactory()` returns null.  I am extremely confused as to why.

I am able to `return new OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter()`, so it is not access to the object from this file.  I am able to get the factory with the provider invariant overload `factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb")`, so it's not a question of having the provider installed, nor of being on the wrong bitness (32 bit) to access the provider.  I am fairly confident the issue is somewhere on the computer itself, since moving this code to the calling project resolves nothing.

How can I get this to return the OleDbDataAdapter from the connection?

Comment: Could try changing your build configuration from Any Cpu to 32bit and see if that makes a difference, or make sure you’re using the 64bit odbc driver.  Other than that, update your question with the exception details that is being thrown

Comment: Can you create the desired data adapter explicitly, rather than through a factory?

Comment: user18387401 Yes, returning a new `OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter` works.

Comment: Hursey Changing to 32 bit results in no change.  There is no exception being thrown inherently - .GetFactory() just returns null.  The only exception thrown is the one I myself wrote in the middle line.

Comment: `.GetFactory() itself is not throwing an exception. It returns null. ` that means no matching factory is configured. This isn't about VS 2022 being 64-bit, it's because the 64-bit OLEDB provider you want wasn't installed on the machine. Had you deployed a 64-bit application in the last 10-15 that used COM you'd run into the same problem. Especially since Office started coming in 64-bit versions. You can't mix 32- and 64-bit versions of Office apps and drivers.

Comment: What are you trying to do ? If you want to work with Excel a *far* better way is to read the `xlsx` file directly using eg ExcelDataReader. `xlsx` is a ZIP package containing well-defined XML files. NuGet packages like `ExcelDataReader` can read it directly

Comment: Sadly it's reading an Access database, not an Excel file.  If I am understanding correctly, the bitness of the Office application, the driver, and the program I am debugging all have to be the same (ie, since I have a 32 bit version of Access, all would have to be 32 bit)?